# CGContextClipToMask does not clip

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext, clipping

This code results in the image below. As far as I understand CGContextClipToMask, the red rectangle should not be visible, since it is outside of the clipped area. What am I missing here? Thanks for any help!

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

// draw partial circle
UIBezierPath *arc   = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:NO];
CGContextAddPath(context, [arc CGPath]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// create mask
CGImageRef mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
self.maskCreated(mask);

// save state
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// clip with mask
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, mask);

// draw test rect
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100));

// restore state
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

[image: Code Result]

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClipToMask) for `CGContextClipToMask` says:

> If mask is an image, then it must be in the DeviceGray color space,
>   may not have an alpha component, and may not be masked by an image
>   mask or masking color.

I'm assuming your code is in a the `-drawRect:` method of a subclass of `UIView`, so you are using the `CGContext` which was provided to you, which is in an RGB color space and probably has an alpha component. Your `mask` image is created from that context, so it gets the same attributes.

To fix this, use a separate bitmap context to generate the mask, using a gray colorspace with no alpha. Here's a self-contained example that does something similar to your code.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Create a context for the mask
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef maskContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Fill with black
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(maskContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(maskContext, rect);

    // Draw an arc in white
    CGContextSetLineWidth(maskContext, 20);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(maskContext, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddArc(maskContext, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect), 50, M_PI, 0, false);
    CGContextStrokePath(maskContext);

    // Create the mask image from the context, and discard the context
    CGImageRef mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(maskContext);
    CGContextRelease(maskContext);

    // Now draw into the view itself
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Apply the mask
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, mask);

    // Then draw something that overlaps the mask
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    // Make sure to clean up when we're done
    CGImageRelease(mask);
}
```

Comment: (Of course, once I was mostly done with this answer, I noticed that the question was more than 2 years old. Oh well, might as well post it anyway.)

Comment: I will check your answer and mark it as correct if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually don't understand your concern, but you can hide rectangle in your method like this:

```
// draw a test rect             
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, the rectangle is not the problem. The problem is, that I create a mask from that arc, but the view and everything I draw after creating the mask is not masked.